# How to instantiate 2 objects of the mbed Ble class?

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, mbed

I’m new to the world of Mbed and trying to simultaneously run a Gatt client and server.

I have read that to do so I need to create 2 different instances of the BLE service.

This is probably crazy easy, but being the noob that I am to C++ I’m not sure how to do that?

Documentation (https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.14/mbed-os-api-doxy/class_b_l_e.html) points to using this method to use a singleton:

`BLE& mydevicename = BLE::Instance();`

As far as I understand, to create multiple instances I need to use the following constructor:

`BLE (InstanceID_t instanceID=DEFAULT_INSTANCE)`

This is what I’m trying in my code:

```
BLE ble1 = BLE(1);
BLE ble2 = BLE(2);
```

but I’m getting the error:
`‘BLE::BLE(const BLE&)’ is private within this context`
which doesn’t make sense to me since I’m not parsing in a BLE object.

Comment: Thanks, changed to C++

Comment: `run a Gatt client and server` I believe that's just not possible. You have _one_ bluetooth device. You can't configure one device to work as two. Do you have two bluetooth transceivers on your device? What about `BLE& ble1 = BLE::Instance(0); BLE& ble2 = BLE::Instance(1)`? But note that "ID shell be less then MAX_INSTANCES" from the documentation you linked.

Comment: this has worked to create 2 instances which as you say actually doesn't seem to work since NUM_INSTANCES is set to 1 :(

This thread seems to say it should be possible somehow though: https://os.mbed.com/questions/84478/Can-I-have-the-nrf52-dk-acting-as-BLE-Se/

Comment: Also you are asking XY question. You don't care about 2 objects of BLE class. You want to run client and server GATT simultaneously. So run them using the same BLE class.

Comment: I had tried to do that previously without success... Blinking lights of death... I'll have to try and modify what I'm doing with it further down the line to see if I can get it to work. 

Thanks for your help, if you put up your first comment as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.